# Função com chamada interna

Tags: javascript

É possível executar uma função apenas no javascript sem utilizar o HTML ? Quero que o script procure a id de um botão no html e que a função onclick apareça apenas no código interno do script, sem que seja necessário chama-la nos atributos do botão como por exemplo "  "
É possível ?

```js
var play;
var controle = document.getElementById('button');

controle.onclick = function teste()
{

  if(document.getElementById("button").value == "Play")
 {
  document.getElementById("button").value = "Pause";
  play = setInterval(trocaBanner,4000);
 } 
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("button").value = "Play";
  clearInterval(play);
 }

}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
      <figure>
       <input type="button" id="button" value="Play" />
       <img src="img/destaque-home.png" alt="Promoção : Big City Night"/
 </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Cara eu acho que você poderia dar uma descrição mais ampla para o que você quer fazer. Edite a pergunta e coloque o contexto do que você tem, o que você quer fazer e como você espera que funcione, porque da forma como está a gente não tem nenhum contexto do que está acontecendo...

Comment: Editei a pergunta, pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Oi pelo que entendi você quer tudo no `onclick` do botão, direto na tag.

No seu javascript a função de tocar banner e as variáveis para controle se quiser declara-las:

```
    var inExecution = false;
    var play;       
    function trocaBanner()
    {
        console.log("baner");
    }
```

No seu HTML:

```
    <section class="banner">
      <figure>
       <input type="button" id="button" value="Play" onclick="(inExecution ? (clearInterval(play), (this).value='Play', inExecution=false) : (play = setInterval(trocaBanner, 4000), (this).value='Pause', inExecution=true));" />
       <img src="img/destaque-home.png" alt="Promoção : Big City Night"/
    </figure>
   </section>
```

Note que fiz um `if` ternário no evento `onclick` do botão para executar todas as funções.

Se quiser colocar em um evento no JS faça:

```
   window.onload = function() {
        var inExecution = false;
        var play;
        var elemento = document.getElementById('button');

        function trocaBanner() {
            console.log("baner");
        }

        elemento.addEventListener('click', function handle (evt) {
            if(inExecution) {
                elemento.value = "Play";
                clearInterval(play);
            } else {
                elemento.value = "Pause";
                play = setInterval(trocaBanner, 4000);
            }
            inExecution = !inExecution;
        });
    };
```

Note que coloquei dentro de `window.onload` para que a função `addEventListener` só adicione o evento ao botão após sua pagina ser carregada. Caso contrário você deverá colocar o script depois do botão para que funcione.

Comment: Não, quero fazer o contrário ao invés de colocar a chamada onclick no html, quero coloca-la e manipular ela apenas no script, entende ?

Comment: Beleza coloque um addEventListener dentro de um window.onload veja como fica.

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue incluir um listener de um evento direto no elemento sem precisar incluir o atributo `onclick` no HTML da seguinte forma:

```js
let play
let elemento = document.getElementById('button')

function handle (e) {
  if(document.getElementById("button").value == "Play") {
    document.getElementById("button").value = "Pause"
    play = setInterval(trocaBanner,4000)
    return
  } 

  document.getElementById("button").value = "Play"
  clearInterval(play)
}

elemento.addEventListener('click', handle)
```

Desta forma você não vai estar modificando o HTML e não vai estar inserindo um novo atributo. Veja o teste [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/Lawv9zds/)

Comment: let é um tipo de variável ? este "e" que você colocou entre parenteses se refere ao elemento "ID" ? 
sua solução é perfeita, mas por favor me ajude a entender como faço algo assim : </br>
document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function() {
// tratamento do evento
};

Comment: Seu código não funciona fora do JSFiddle

Comment: let é uma variável. Segundo w3schools -> https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_let.asp ela é uma variável de escopo somente acessível ao bloco a que pertence ex: { let a=0; }.

Comment: `let` é a versão 2015 do Javascript... Já está funcionando em todos os browsers maiores em suas últimas versões. Você pode substituir pelo `var` também, a diferença é que `let` é preso ao escopo do bloco enquanto var é declarado fora do escopo do bloco

Comment: Este código deve funcionar em qualquer lugar desde que esteja atualizado. Qual é o browser que você está atendendo ao fazer essa funcionalidade?

Comment: Estou usando o Chrome, vou tentar novamente e depois e comento denovo

Comment: Estranho cara, eu inclusive fiz o teste dessa versão no Chrome. Veja qual é a versão que está sendo utilizada, eu estou na 72